# Installing JDK in Linux - the download file appears to be corrupted

Tags: linux

I have downloaded JDK, but when I am trying to extract it, I am facing these errors:

```
[root@ras java]# . jdk-6u26-linux-i586.bin
Unpacking...
tail: cannot open `bash' for reading: No such file or directory
Checksumming...
The download file appears to be corrupted.  Please refer
to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation
Instructions on the download page for more information.
Please do not attempt to install this archive file.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@ras ~]#
```

What do I do to fix it?

Comment: `cannot open 'bash' for reading: No such file or directory ` is probably pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
chmod +x jdk-6u26-linux-i586.bin
./jdk-6u26-linux-i586.bin
```